# 3G modem connects and ping is working, can't access web

Tags: networking, gsm, modem, networkmanager

Huawei E369 3G modem connected to RPi3 Model A+ and managed by NetworkManager cli:

- connects
- allows for pinging websites
- has working DNS

But does not allow for performing any http requests using CURL so:

`ping -I ppp0 www.google.com` works but

`curl --interface ppp0 www.google.com` does not.

The closest to my issue I found is [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=214169) on Raspberry Pi forums but it is inconclusive to me what changed fixed it.

I've plugged modem on Mint and it works so I've compared outputs from `nmcli device show` side by side and found differences (MTU set to 0 and no routes on RPI):

Raspberry

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ttyUSB1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           gsm
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     plus
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         31.2.90.38/32
IP4.GATEWAY:                            31.2.90.38
IP4.DNS[1]:                             212.2.127.254
IP4.DNS[2]:                             212.2.96.54
```

Mint Desktop

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ttyUSB1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           gsm
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Plus Standard access 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/8
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         46.169.152.5/32
IP4.GATEWAY:                            46.169.152.5
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 46.169.152.5/32, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 700
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 46.169.152.5, mt = 700
IP4.DNS[1]:                             212.2.127.254
IP4.DNS[2]:                             212.2.96.52
```

For completeness I attach output from `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    302    0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         31.2.90.38      0.0.0.0         UG    700    0        0 ppp0
31.2.90.38      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    700    0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     302    0        0 wlan0
```

And `mmcli -m 0`:

```
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 (device id '1668e1f193c8f1f8cf30b97abb39eb278ed191d6')
  -------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: 'Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.'
           |          model: 'E369'
           |       revision: '41.102.18.00.264'
           |      supported: 'gsm-umts'
           |        current: 'gsm-umts'
           |   equipment id: '868414002630527'
  -------------------------
  System   |         device: '/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1'
           |        drivers: 'option1'
           |         plugin: 'Huawei'
           |   primary port: 'ttyUSB1'
           |          ports: 'ttyUSB0 (at), ttyUSB1 (at)'
  -------------------------
  Numbers  |           own : 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  Status   |           lock: 'none'
           | unlock retries: 'sim-pin (3), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk (10), sim-puk2 (10)'
           |          state: 'connected'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'edge'
           | signal quality: '100' (recent)
  -------------------------
  Modes    |      supported: 'allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: none'
           |        current: 'allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: none'
  -------------------------
  Bands    |      supported: 'unknown'
           |        current: 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  IP       |      supported: 'ipv4'
  -------------------------
  3GPP     |           imei: '<imei>'
           |  enabled locks: 'none'
           |    operator id: '26001'
           |  operator name: '0050006C00750073'
           |   subscription: 'unknown'
           |   registration: 'home'
  -------------------------
  SIM      |           path: '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0'

  -------------------------
  Bearers  |          paths: '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/0'
```

and configuration in network manager system connections:

```
[connection]
id=Plus Standard access 1
uuid=b4c6111d-8735-46ed-9b51-60887a84ec7a
type=gsm
autoconnect=false
permissions=user:pi:;
interface=ttyUSB1

[gsm]
apn=www.plusgsm.pl
home-only=true
number=*99#
password-flags=0
username=plusgsm

[gsm-secrets]
password=plusgsm

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto
```

Comment: What OS? Why are you using Network Manager?

Comment: Raspbian Stretch Lite, I got stuck with connecting using wvdial and sakis3g managed to configure almost everything but got stuck during connection phase. So I decided to give network manager a try since it was able to establish connection on Mint Desktop.

Comment: Network Manager is not used by Raspbian - you are free to try (you haven't said what you did), but you are likely to get more help using one of the standard Raspbian tools. It appears that you still have other networking running.

Comment: Which tools are considered standard for Raspberry Pi modem connectivity? wvdial & pppd combination? Or sakis-3g script?

I've tried using sakis-3g on Mint desktop and it doesn't work either - so at least it's consistent. Whatever graphical version of NetworkManager is doing additionally on Mint is making connection work :) I'll notify here about my progress.

Comment: Looks like you have two default routes (Destination 0.0.0.0).  The system can only use one of the default routes, so delete the default route for wlan0 so that all non-local traffic is sent to ppp0.  I think your ping command worked because "-I ppp0" tells ping which interface to use without going through the routing table.

Comment: It does looks so - on desktop with mint I've noticed that when I have both wifi & modem then curl on ppp0 usually doesn't work and starts working immediately when I turn wifi off - this corresponds with one default route less - so again it looks like you're right. Does removal of this default route mean that I will no longer be able to log into raspberry from my local network wifi? Or does it mean that only all outgoing requests will go through cellular network? (e.g. I should be careful with apt-get then)

Comment: @ChadFarmer ok removing wlan0 default route resolved the issue, do you want to answer the question so that I can mark it as accepted answer or do you want me to answer it with details on what I've done? In short I've run `sudo ip route del default via 192.168.1.1`

Comment: Go ahead and answer it.  I wasn't near a RPi to do the work for a real answer.  You can show command output, etc.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chad Farmer mentioned the issue was with having two default routes (Destination 0.0.0.0). So assuming that you have the same issue and `route -n` output that looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    302    0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         31.2.90.38      0.0.0.0         UG    700    0        0 ppp0
31.2.90.38      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    700    0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     302    0        0 wlan0
```

Then in order to fix the issue you need to run:

`sudo ip route del default via 192.168.1.1` (ip addres of default gateway on wlan0 interface)

After this `route -n` output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         31.2.90.38      0.0.0.0         UG    700    0        0 ppp0
31.2.90.38      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    700    0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     302    0        0 wlan0
```

and `curl --interface ppp0 www.google.com` finally starts to work as do other http requests.

> Important note is that outgoing traffic will now go through mobile connection so be careful with apt-get.

Comment: It is possible to create multiple routing tables in Linux so that you can have a different default route in each table.  You create routing rules for selecting which table to use.  How to do that is off-topic for this question and somewhat complicated.  Search for iproute2 if you need more than one default route (multiple different gateway routers).

Comment: Thanks, I only periodically open mobile connection to send telemetry so multiple routing tables sounds like perfect solution for me.